# Swift изменение label при нажатии на ячейку таблицы другого класса

Tags: xcode, swift

Во первых, есть ViewController, в нем находятся две tableView. Одна таблица принадлежит ViewController, а другая иному классу. Вопрос первый, можно ли сделать две tableView на одно viewController без использования других классов? Ибо у меня не вышло. 
И во вторых, исходя из того, что у меня две таблицы с разными классами, но находятся на одном ViewController, мне нужно изменить label при нажатии на ячейку второй таблицы другого класса, но он не видит label, так как он в другом классе. Можно ли как-то взаимодействовать с label, который в другом классе? Либо же как можно поместить две таблицы в один viewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView1: UITableView!

/// A simple data structure to populate the table view.
struct PreviewDetail {
    let title: String
    let preferredHeight: Double
}

let sampleData = [
    PreviewDetail(title: "Small", preferredHeight: 160.0),
    PreviewDetail(title: "Medium", preferredHeight: 320.0),
    PreviewDetail(title: "Large", preferredHeight: 0.0) // 0.0 to get the default height.
]

let sampleData1 = [
    PreviewDetail(title: "One", preferredHeight: 160.0),
    PreviewDetail(title: "Two", preferredHeight: 320.0),
    PreviewDetail(title: "Three", preferredHeight: 0.0), // 0.0 to get the default height.
    PreviewDetail(title: "More", preferredHeight: 0.0) // 0.0 to get the default height.
]



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    tableView1.dataSource = self
    tableView1.delegate = self
    tableView1.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell1")


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // Return the number of items in the sample data structure.

    var count:Int?

    if tableView == self.tableView {
        count = sampleData.count
    }

    if tableView == self.tableView1 {
        count =  sampleData1.count
    }

    return count!

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell:UITableViewCell?

    if tableView == self.tableView {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        let previewDetail = sampleData[indexPath.row]
        cell!.textLabel!.text = previewDetail.title

    }

    if tableView == self.tableView1 {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        let previewDetail = sampleData1[indexPath.row]
        cell!.textLabel!.text = previewDetail.title

    }



    return cell!
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("did select:      \(indexPath.row)  ")
 }
```

}

Comment: спасибо, код немного подправить пришлось, а так все как нужно)) спасибо!